# How do I log a URL encode if it's a private method?

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby 1.9.1 or 1.9.3, I have a problem inserting the `%` symbol into a database.

The exception is:

```
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:898:in `decode_www_form_component'
```

I was told to use `p` to output `str`.

This is ruby/lib/1.9.1/util/common.rb:

```
def self.decode_www_form_component(str, enc=Encoding::UTF_8)  

  require 'logger'  
  # Keep data for the current month only  
  $LOG = Logger.new('this_month.log', 'monthly')  
  $LOG.debug("#{str.p}")      

  raise ArgumentError, "invalid %-encoding (#{str})" unless /\A[^%]*(?:%\h\h[^%]*)*\z/ =~ str
  str.gsub(/\+|%\h\h/, TBLDECWWWCOMP_).force_encoding(enc)
end
```

I got this error:

```
Internal Server Error
cannot parse Cookie header: private method `p' called for "innate.sid":String
```

How do I `p` `str` to find out what's inside it and maybe what encoding it is?

Comment: You are modifying URI's code? Don't do that! It's very easy to write a method that will override it in your own code, or simply wrap it and output to the log. If you change system or core code you affect every other script that will use that method, which can have bad results if there's an error. One of the best features of an OO-language is we can override without having to change the base class code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `p` method if you're using logger. `p` and `puts` output to stdout.

```
# this is equavalent to `puts str`
$LOG.debug(str)

# for more "raw" data
# `p str` or `puts str.inspect`
$LOG.debug(str.inspect)
```